# Algebra/polynomials contest-math problem about sum of squares of coefficients

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

The problem states:
If roots of $x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + ax + 1 = 0$ are real, find the minimum value of

$$a^2 + b^2$$

Im really not very good at these types of questions as they seemingly provide very little information.

So, I am basically stumped by this. I first thought that, since the roots are real, $x^4$ and $x^2$ should be positive, which would imply the others are negative. But wont know anything about $a$ or $b$, so really Ive no idea. Id like a hint and not the full solution, so that I can get better at solving such problems. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the source of the question, and if applicable, the date of the competition.

Comment: This is some IMO form 70's

Comment: @Macavity all roots

Comment: Another, perhaps simpler way: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h565698p3309169

Comment: @amWhy Its from the British Mathematical Olympiad, my book dosent mention the year

Comment: See also here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h58582

Answer (score 1):

Divide the equation by $x^2$ and set $y=x+\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Only when $x\neq 0$.

Comment: That's perhaps a first step or hint.  So you get $y^2+ay+(b-2)=0$ must have two solutions with $y \in \mathbb R \setminus (-2, 2)$.  From there you still need to reach the distant minimum for $a^2+b^2$...